# In flow, given ?boolean variables, how to check if 'either of them is true' without encountering sketchy null check?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

`x` and `y` are both `?boolean`. I want to return true if either x or y is true.

`x || y` does not work as it complains about sketchy null check.

Comment: just disable it `sketchy-null-bool=off` or make additional checks for null

Comment: What's `?` in front of `?boolean`? And... what's the problem with OR?

Comment: @FZs it's Flow syntax, optional field type

Comment: Based on basically nothing you could try `x || y || false` which should always return a `boolean` (if both `x` and `y` are known to be `?boolean`).

Comment: `x === true || y === true`.